# find binary linked to a process which crashes soon as launched?

Tags: command-line, process

Program A after checking the system configuration executes one of Programs B, C or D. When I run Program A, it launches one of these and newly launched program crashes (takes less than a second). This prevents me from finding the file via /proc mount. Is there a way to know which program was launched?

Running Program A in gdb didn't help because the the system configuration read by Program A changed and it launched a different program. All these binaries (A, B, C and D) are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot put a trace, I'd suggest you temporarily rename B, C, and D. Assuming A will tell you that B, C, or D are missing, you should get the info you need.

If it doesn't tell you but still generate an error saying the next process is missing, you may try to rename just B and C and see what happens. Then try again with just B and D. At that point you should know whether B, C, or D is the culprit.

Also, you may be able to manually try each one and see if only one or even all have problems starting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Never thought about renaming the executables. Thanks.